What is causing "Thunderbird is already running" error if mailbox on SAMBA mount
On Xubuntu 22.04 and 24.04 If a thunderbird mailbox is on a SAMBA controlled Ubuntu mount, starting thunderbird I am getting the error screen which begins:

Thunderbird is already running, but is not responding. To use Thunderbird, you must first close the existing Thunderbird process, restart your device, or use a different profile.

I've tried having 22.04 own the mailbox with 24.04 having access through a SAMBA mount to 22.04 - this failure on 24.04 - sucess on 22.04 (ie the system where it actually resides.)
I've tried having 24.04 own the mailbox with 22.04 having access through a SAMBA mount to 24.04 - this failure on 22.04 - success on 24.04 (again, the system where it actually resides.)
Accessing the SAMBA mounted mailbox which actually resides on Ubuntu 22.04 from a Ubuntu 16.04 has always succeeded and still does.
If I delete .parentlock  - it still fails
I've had instances in the past of permission problems on a mailbox  - permissions are wide open (set to 777 ie. wrxwrxwrx) on every part of the mailbox
I've checked for thunderbird running with   ps  -ef  |  grep  "hunder"     No active process contains that string.
My mailboxes are shared across several systems by being mounted at a specific mount location - always the same mount point on all systems.  My Xubuntu 16.04 and my Xubuntu 22.04 are able to get to the mailbox. Only the new 24.04 is failing with this error.
I've tried the snap version and, a manual install from a Mozilla tar ball.  Always the same failure.

What's with the down vote? Per the pop up when hovering over down voting  "That would be when someone hasn't done prior research".  Removing a major snap package, placing a Mozilla tar ball in it's place and going back over years of previous notes prior to asking a question is prior research.  Now if the down-voter were to suggest a solution to this 'trivial' question - that would be a very positive addition to this board.

No clue in my logs.  I am about to amend this one or, make an additional question because I really need to get this resolved and I am trying what I would consider off-the-wall possibilities.  If I copy a mailbox off the share it works.  It's not timing because my next attempt was to copy the mailbox onto a thumb drive and that worked as well.  This test with mailbox on thumb drive demonstrates it isn't a time issue.  It is this SAMBA surprise that has me thinking of formatting a question in that direction, after a few more checks.

Perhaps switch from a SAMBA type mount to a network file system (NFS) type mount.

It works but I have no idea why an NFS mount works yet a SAMBA mount does not.  Back in the days of Ubuntu 16.04 SAMBA mounts worked.

NFS and CIFS (SMB) speak completely different protocols and rules, and you have to make sure your system is working in the proper SMB rules.  SMB has all sorts of extra controls NFS doesn't have because it needs Windows CIFS compatibility (the Samba protocol anyways) so.  Might be related to it being 100s of times more complex.

I had the same problem.
The cause of this is that in ~/.thunderbird/profiles.ini I list a profile path that is outside /home in a data directory that sees regular back ups.
thunderbird is in snap now, and snaps are hardcoded (How to give snaps access to /somedir) to permit no data access beyond /home.
This is the reason it could not start any more.
More info see

As per the tags on the question, this was observed in both 22.04 and 24.04.  Both installations are direct from the Thunderbird tar ball.  In short, no SNAP.  Changing to a NFS mount made it work.
